# Getting user input from a dialog using Mortar + Flow

Tags: java, android, mortar, square-flow

I'm build my app with [Mortar](https://github.com/square/mortar) + [Flow](https://github.com/square/flow). I'm trying to figure out the correct way to show a popup that requests some text from the user. I've created this popup class:

```
public class SavedPageTitleInputPopup implements Popup<SavedPageTitleInput, Optional<String>> {

private final Context context;

private AlertDialog dialog;

public SavedPageTitleInputPopup(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override public Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

@Override
public void show(final SavedPageTitleInput info, boolean withFlourish,
                 final PopupPresenter<SavedPageTitleInput, Optional<String>> presenter) {
    if (dialog != null) throw new IllegalStateException("Already showing, can't show " + info);

    final EditText input = new EditText(context);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    input.setLayoutParams(lp);
    input.setText(info.savedPage.getName());

    dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).setTitle(info.title)
                                             .setView(input)
                                             .setMessage(info.body)
                                             .setPositiveButton(info.confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                 @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which) {
                                                     dialog = null;
                                                     final String newTitle = Strings.emptyToNull(String.valueOf(input.getText()));
                                                     presenter.onDismissed(Optional.fromNullable(newTitle));
                                                 }
                                             })
                                             .setNegativeButton(info.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                                 @Override public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which) {
                                                     dialog = null;
                                                     presenter.onDismissed(Optional.<String>absent());
                                                 }
                                             })
                                             .setCancelable(true)
                                             .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                                                 @Override public void onCancel(DialogInterface d) {
                                                     dialog = null;
                                                     presenter.onDismissed(Optional.<String>absent());
                                                 }
                                             })
                                             .show();
}

@Override public boolean isShowing() {
    return dialog != null;
}

@Override public void dismiss(boolean withFlourish) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    dialog = null;
}
}
```

This class works as expected. It uses the `SavedPage` to figure out what to display in the dialog and it returns the users input to the `PopupPresenter` using [PopupPresenter#onDismissed](https://github.com/square/mortar/blob/master/mortar/src/main/java/mortar/PopupPresenter.java#L77) when the correct button is pressed.

My problem is writing the `PopupPresenter` subclass used to present the dialog and process the input. This is what I have right now:

```
new PopupPresenter<SavedPage, Optional<String>>() {
  @Override protected void onPopupResult(Optional<String> result) {
    if (result.isPresent()) {
      // The user entered something, so update the API 
      // Oh wait, I don't have a reference to the SavedPage
      // that was displayed in the dialog!
    }
  }
}
```

As the comments say, I don't have a reference to the `SavedPage` that was displayed in the dialog. It was stored in the `whatToShow` field in `PopupPresenter`, but this field is nulled out right before `onPopupResult` is called. It seems like I would be unnecessarily repeating myself to keep an additional copy of the `SavedPage`.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a lot of documentation yet on [PopupPresenter](https://github.com/square/mortar/blob/master/mortar/src/main/java/mortar/PopupPresenter.java) and [Popup](https://github.com/square/mortar/blob/master/mortar/src/main/java/mortar/Popup.java). The only thing I have seen is a basic example in the sample project. They create a [ConfirmerPopup](https://github.com/square/mortar/blob/master/mortar-sample/src/main/java/com/example/mortar/view/ConfirmerPopup.java) based on data within the [Confirmation](https://github.com/square/mortar/blob/master/mortar-sample/src/main/java/com/example/mortar/view/Confirmation.java) object.  The purpose of the ConfirmerPopup is to capture a boolean decision from the user based on the title/body given to the Confirmation object as seen by the class declaration.

```
public class ConfirmerPopup implements Popup<Confirmation, Boolean> {
```

In your case you want to capture additional user inputted text from the user. When PopupPresenter#onPopupResult is called the result object should contain all of the data needed from SavedPageTitleInputPopup.  Modify your SavedPageTitleInputPopup as follows

```
public class SavedPageTitleInputPopup implements Popup<SavedPage, SavedPageResults> {
  private final Context context;
  private AlertDialog dialog;

  public SavedPageTitleInputPopup(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
  }

  @Override public Context getContext() {
    return context;
  }

  @Override
  public void show(SavedPage info, boolean withFlourish, final PopupPresenter<SavedPage, SavedPageResults> presenter) {
    if (dialog != null) throw new IllegalStateException("Already showing, can't show " + info);
    // Create your Dialog but scrape all user data within OnClickListeners
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    //Anything else you need to do... .setView() or .setTitle() for example
    builder.setPositiveButton(info.confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which) {
        dialog = null;
        //Save data to SavedPageResults
        final SavedPageResults results = new SavedPageResults():
        presenter.onDismissed(results);
      }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(info.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which) {
        dialog = null;
        final SavedPageResults results = new SavedPageResults();
        presenter.onDismissed(results);
      }
    });
    dialog = builder.show();
  }

  @Override public boolean isShowing() {
    return dialog != null;
  }

  @Override public void dismiss(boolean withFlourish) {
    dialog.dismiss();
    dialog = null;
  }
}
```

Your PopupPresenter doesn't need to know anything about the Dialog's implementation now.

```
new PopupPresenter<SavedPage, SavedPageResults>() {
  @Override protected void onPopupResult(SavedPageResults result) {
    if (result.isPresent()) {
      updateUi(result.getSavedText());  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've already seen the `ConfirmerPopup` example and modified it so that my dialog is displayed like I want it. As I mentioned in the question, my problem has to do with keeping a reference to the `whatToShow` field in the `PopupPresenter`. I don't think you answered that.

Comment: You shouldn't need a reference to `whatToShow`. What do you need to access in `onPopupResult` that you can't get within the `OnClickListener`?

Comment: @scompt.com if you update your question with your full `SavedPageTitleInputPopup` and `popup.xml` I will show you what I mean.

Comment: I've added the full `SavedPageTitleInputPopup`. I would like a reference to the `SavedPageTitleInput` instance that I pass to `show`, but it's nulled out before the `onPopupResult` call is made.

Comment: Thanks @scompt.com. What is the reason behind needing a reference to SavedPageTitleInput? What are you trying to do?